# Does Rolle's Theorem handle degenerate intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

Background: I'm studying elementary calculus and have stumbled across a question that may be above my paygrade.

I understand Rolle's Theorem to state that a function which is continuous on [a, b] and differentiable on (a, b) will have a point p (a < p < b) such that f'(p) is 0, so long as f(a) = f(b).

Does Rolle's Theorem handle what I've just discovered are called degenerate intervals? It would seem not. Why not? Or does it?

Comment: What is a degenerate interval?

Comment: THe biggest problem that I see here is that if $a=b$ (which I assume is the definition of "degenerate" that you are using), then there is no $p\in(a,b)$.

Comment: It is sort of meaningless. The point of Rolle's theorem is that between any two distinct points with the same function value that there must be a minimizer or a maximizer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: absolutely not. It is an implicit assumption that $a<b.$ We really can't avoid it, it turns out. Given ***any*** real-valued function $f$ defined on a non-empty subset of the reals, we can certainly say that $f$ is continuous on $[a,a]$ for any $a$ in the domain of $f,$ and we can certainly say that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,a)=\emptyset,$ because **all** functions are differentiable there. But there is certainly no $p$ such that $a<p<a$, and so the rest falls apart.

Put another way: if Rolle's Theorem could handle degenerate intervals, then *there would always be a point between any given point*. (What the heck does that even mean?)

Comment: This is great. I missed the significance that p must be on the _open_ interval (a, b). That would mean that it is not the case that every closed interval [a, b] contains the open interval (a, b)! Anyone care to elaborate on this?

Comment: Well, that's not really true. Every closed interval $$[a,b]:=\{x\in\Bbb R:a\le x\le b\}$$ rather trivially contains the open interval $$(a,b):=\{x\in\Bbb R:a<x<b\}.$$ It's simply that when $a\ge b,$ we have that $[a,b]$ has at most one point, and $(a,b)$ is empty. These (and the corresponding half-open, half-closed intervals) are the degenerate intervals.